# Authentication error with Blockchain Wallet API

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I successfully integrated the `blockchain-wallet-api` into an application which is currently on production. The challenge I'm having is that even though I was able to disable email login authentication from my wallet settings and added the shared hosting `ip` to ip whitelist, I still get the error

```
Array ( [error] => Wallets that require email authorization are currently not supported in the Wallet API. Please disable this in your wallet settings, or add the IP address of this server to your wallet IP whitelist. )
```

I don't know what else to do.